# How to get foreignKey data from MultipleChoiceField in django?

Tags: python, django

my models.py

```
relay = models.ForeignKey(RelayAddress,related_name="relay")
sister_relay = models.ForeignKey(RelayAddress,related_name="sister_relay")
"RelayAddress" is another table
```

my admin.py

```
sister = RelayAddress.objects.all()
dict=[]
for i in sister:
    dict.append((i.id,i.display_name()))
    #sister_relay_id=forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(label=u'sister_relay',widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),queryset=RelayAddress.objects.all())
    sister_relay_id=forms.MultipleChoiceField(label=u'sister_relay',widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),choices=dict)
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    u = self.instance
my_list =self.cleaned_data['sister_relay_id']
...
...
return super(RelaySisterRelationForm, self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

the question is:

when I save , error happend,"cannot assign[u'1']:RelayAddress.sister_relay must be RelayAddress instance"(like this)

if I not use ForeignKey in the model,it can work.

but I want use ForeignKey and checkbox at same time,get more than one data from checkbox as a list,and save at my will.

I also tried "ModelMultipleChoiceField",not work.

how should I do?  Thanks for help very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need a [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield):

```
sister_relay=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=RelayAddress.objects.all())
```

Then in your *view*:

```
if request.method.POST:
    form = RelayForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
       obj = form.save(commit=False)
       obj.sister_relay = form.cleaned_data['sister_relay']
       obj.save()
```

The value of a `ModelChoiceField` will be converted into an instance of the queryset.

Answer (score 0):

What I don't understand about your code is that how could you store a list into a ForeignKey field.

If your model should could have multiple "sister_relay", this field should be a ManyToManyField instead of a ForeignKey field. If you do so the ModelMultipleChoiceField will work perfectly.

If the model should not have multiple "sister_relay", then there's no reason to use MultipleChoiceField in the form, a ModelChoiceField will be enough.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/